# link to other pages in twig template

Tags: symfony, routes, twig

I would like to know something. In Symfony documentation I can read that I can use **path(route)** in twig pages to link to another page.

Doing so in my project, the url is strange.

for example :

```
{{ path('_home') }} displays app_dev.php/home/
```

why is that ? should not it be /home so routing can work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are in the development environment `app_dev.php` will be prepended to all of your paths, otherwise you would only ever be able to test one page at a time without having to manually change the current URL.

When you move to production (starting without the `app_dev.php` in the URL) it will not be prepended to your path.